# How to make sortable column in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, money-rails

I have column on index page in ActiveAdmin:

```rb
column("Credit amount", sortable: true) {|u| u.credit_amount.format }
```

I'm using gem `money-rails` for `:credit_amount` and `.format` method on index page for readability.

But sorting doesn't work.
How can I make sorting from largest to smallest and vice versa for this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```rb
column("Credit amount", sortable: 'products.credit_amount_cents') {|u| u.credit_amount.format }
```

Just make sure to replace `products` with whatever table name you have.